# Terms new to beginners in c++?

Tags: c++

What does it mean by POD type?cv-qualified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Nice article on [POD](http://www.fnal.gov/docs/working-groups/fpcltf/Pkg/ISOcxx/doc/POD.html)

Answer (score 8):

POD, Plain Old Data, is any C++ type that has an equivalent in C.

cv-qualified type is a type that have been qualified either as a const or volatile.

```
// non cv_qualified
int one; 
char *two; 

// cv-qualified 
const int three; 
volatile char * four;
```

POD type's data members must be public and can be of any the primitive types: bool, numeric types, enumeration types, data-pointer types, pointer-to-function type, also arrays of any of the previous.

```
struct A //POD
{
 int n;
 double y;
};

struct B //non-POD
{
private:
 int n;
 double y;
};
```

Comment: what things in c++ that makes c++ type non equivalent to c

Comment: POD type is defined recursively, I think. Your definition leaves out "or any other POD type".

Comment: I agree with Arkadiy: AFAIK, a POD can contain PODs and/or built-in types.

Answer (score 5):

**POD** stands for **Plain Old Data** type.  It usually refers to a class that is used to hold data and accessors---nothing else.  It is also implied that the function does not have a vtable, which means that there are no polymorphic members of the class.  These are popular for lightweight objects where you don't want to pay the price of the polymorphic class overhead.

**CV-qualified**.  **C=Const, V=Volatile**.

Comment: Or pointers, for that matter. Basically all non-class types are PODs too IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

> what things in c++ that makes c++ type
>   non equivalent to c – rajKumar

As CMS said, a POD type is a C++ type that has an equivalent in C: so, it has to follow the same rules C uses for:

- initialization
- copying
- layout
- addressing

The C++ type should **not** have any constructor, must **not** overload the assignment operator, must **not** have virtual functions, base classes, destructor and also non-static members that are private or protected.